# Check if nlog message will be used

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am using Common.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger().Trace() to output table content into nlog logs. 
Querying SQL is not the kind of operation you want to perform unless someone has turned on trace filter in nlog.

```
    this.log.TraceFormat("After import: \r\n" + SqlHelper.GetSqlResults("select * from " + atomDefinition.Table.FullName));
```

Is there a way I can bypass that line if it will not be emitted to any log due to current nlog configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

Set a key in your config file and check it before making the call.

```
if(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[shouldLog] == "true") {
    this.log.TraceFormat("Af....
}
```